# Meaning of "Сходить сонце у крисані" in "Народився Бог на санях"

Tags: значення-слів

From *[Народився Бог на санях](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW7pRVR5cYs)*:

> **Сходить сонце у крисані**,
>   Спить слав’янськеє дитя.
>   Їдуть сани, плаче Пані,
>   Снігом стелиться життя.

([Wikipedia article](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%85))

Does it mean "the Sun arises **above** the hat"?  Is this hat on the head of one of the "лемкив"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In English:

In Bohdan-Ihor Antonych's poetry, it's about Jesus Christ who came to the Earth as a human being to be closer to people. There is a line in this poetry:

["Народився Бог на санях, Прийшли **лемки у крисанях**"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%85) (English: God was born on a sled, [Lemkos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemkos) in krysanias (hats) arrived),

where a poet depicts the traditional picture of [lemko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemkos) as one who strolls around in a hat, which is called "**крисаня**" (krysania).

So, God that came to this world in a human body as the author sees it, should look like traditional [lemko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemkos). There's a proof to it in the article of [Vira Bilyk, "Деякі міфологічні образи й мотиви поезії Б.-І. АНТОНИЧА"](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/folklore/38/21.pdf) ("Some of the mythological pictures and motives in the poetry of B-I Antonych"):

> далі сонце набуває уже зовсім людських рис: воно "ходить у **крисані"**.
>
> then the sun gets more and more human features: it "strolls around in **krysani** (hats)"

as well as in the article of [Jurij Kovaliv (Kyiv)
"МІФЕМНІ КОДИ ПОЕТИЧНОГО МОВЛЕННЯ Б.-І. АНТОНИЧА"](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/folklore/38/21.pdf) ("Mytheme codes of the poetic language of B-I Antonych"):

> Б.-І. Антонич незрідка «одомашнював» образну систему міфологемного
> походження (над лемками «місяць лине срібним калачиком», «В ріці дівчата
> сонце миють», «**сонце ходить у крисані»** тощо),

#### In Ukrainian:

В поезії Богдана-Ігоря Антонича, очевидно, йдеться про те, що Ісус Христос прийшов на землю в образі людини, щоб бути ближче до людей. Оскільки, вище у цій поезії подається: ["Народився Бог на санях, Прийшли **лемки у крисанях**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%85)", то  поет саме так вималював традиційний образ лемка, який ходить у капелюсі, що називається **крисаня**.

Тому, Бог, який прийшов на світ у людській подобі в уяві автора має виглядає як традиційний представник лемків. Підтвердження цього знаходимо у статті [Віра Білик, "Деякі міфологічні образи й мотиви поезії Б.-І. АНТОНИЧА](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/folklore/38/21.pdf):

> далі сонце набуває уже зовсім людських рис: воно "ходить у **крисані"**.

також у статті [Юрій КОВАЛІВ (Київ)
МІФЕМНІ КОДИ ПОЕТИЧНОГО МОВЛЕННЯ Б.-І. АНТОНИЧА](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/folklore/38/21.pdf)

> Б.-І. Антонич незрідка «одомашнював» образну систему міфологемного
> походження (над лемками «місяць лине срібним калачиком», «В ріці дівчата
> сонце миють», «**сонце ходить у крисані»** тощо),